# Changed bundle resources not being installed when updating iOS app from App Store

Tags: ios, xcode

When installing app updates via the app store, the update is not installing changes in bundle resources, specifically a folder that contains an sqlite file and image assets.  Consequently users don't see any changes to these files reflected in their installed app.  When the app is deleted from the device and re-installed the changes are installed.

The same behavior occurs in Xcode.  Building the app to the device installs the changed bundle resources only if the app is deleted from the device, otherwise the changes are ignored.

Looking for a way to force the changes to the bundle resources in the user's installed app.

Comment: I Have the same question. Any soluiton?